# Http response errero:no such file or directory

Tags: genymotion

Today, I wanna to add a virtual on Genymotion, when downloading the file, I got this error:

> Http response error: no such file or directory.

But when I launch Genymotion by root, then it works well. I guess the reason for this error is Permissions issue. Do you known launch it as a general user, and avoid this problem? Thank u very much.

Comment: Where did you get this error message? Can you include the last lines of ~/.Genymobile/genymotion.log?